# Chrome launcher display open tabs

Tags: google-chrome, launcher

Currently running Ubuntu 22.04.

I got my Chrome Launcher on panel to open new tab on left click, but I was wondering if there is a way to have the below functionality.

When left clicking launcher, if any instances of Chrome are open it will display them and allow me to select an instance, or else it will open a new tab, somewhat similar to this.

[image: display open tabs of same program]

I would just like to be able to quickly open any of the instances of Chrome. Other programs aren't as important, but in the above image it seems this functionality was baseline, showing 'arrows' for each active instance of an app.

Similar to Windows behavior. I'm just curious if this is possible.